# 100+ Products with 200+ Variations each. Is WooCommerce not for us?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My company is selling fabric-wrapped bulletin-board-like panels.
[You can see our old store here and get an idea as to what we want to do with the new store.](http://www.fabricmatestore.com/p-3-anchorage-tackboard.aspx)
The base product is the panel size: 12" x 12" or 36" x 48" etc...
Each panel has 3 Variation Attributes: 3 Frame Colors, 2 Edge Profiles & 5-45 Fabric Colors

We're using the WooCommerce CSV Import Suite, building the products and their variations in excel and importing the csv's.  We import the variations at around 200 a time because doing more has a tendency to lock up the import process.

These imports seem to work fine aside from the fact that we can't do anything else with the site while it's importing.  The problem occurs when we try to go to the store and test the products.

I'll use our Anchorage Panels as an example of the issue.
There are 14 sizes for Anchorage with 208 variations per product.
If I have 8 of the 14 products published the page loads fine and the products work great but changing 1 more product from draft to published causes the page to load blank; as in not at all.
It doesn't matter which 8 of the 14 I publish.

I've nested the panels into subcategories to try and fix the problem but there always seems to be a limit.  Originally I had all of these Tackable Panels loading on one page but ran into this same problem which led me to nesting them into subcategories.

Is WooCommerce just not capable of handling this kind of thing?  I've barely touched the surface with what needs to be in the store for when we launch and already it seems taxed to the limit.

Comment: WooCommerce is probably not the right solution.  For e-commerce of this scale I'd recommend something like [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/)

Comment: Thank you, that's what we figured.  We've decided to change everything to simple products and now it's working flawlessly.